# Let $~V_1,V_2 \in \mathbb R^2$. If span $~\{V_1,V_2\} = \mathbb R^2~$ then $~\{V_1,V_2\} ~$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $~V_1,V_2 \in \mathbb R^2$. If span $~\{V_1,V_2\} = \mathbb R^2~$ then $~\{V_1,V_2\} ~$ is linearly independent

How can I prove it ?

base on what ?

Comment: Welcome to [Math SE!](https://math.stackexchange.com/) . Please read this  [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to begin with and share your thoughts and efforts in the question .

Comment: Also, this has very little to do with calculus

Comment: Prove that if they are linearly dependent, then $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ are not in the span

Answer (score 2):

If $v_1,v_2$ are linearly dependent, that means $av_1+bv_2=0$ for some $a,b\in \Bbb R$ such that $a\ne 0$ or $b\ne 0$.

Assuming $b\ne 0$, we have $v_2=(-a/b)v_1$, and thus $\mathrm{span}(v_1,v_2)=\{tv_1:t\in\Bbb R\}$ which is not the whole $\Bbb R^2$, as any vector non parallel to $v_1$ is missing.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  If $v_1$ and $v_2$ were linearly dependent,  then $\Bbb R^2$ would have dimension $\le1$, since, for instance,  we would have $\Bbb R^2=\operatorname {span}\{v_1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In order for any 2 vectors to span $R^2$, they have to be linearly independent.